# Fonts imported into css apply in development server but not in deployed production build

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I have a React app created via `npx create-react-app` and I have imported two fonts into the `App.css` file.
This is the relevant CSS code:

```css
@import url(https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/bcbeab8fa70d1d1899cd5c6993cd67b9?family=UniSansW01-Heavy);
@import url(https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/294afa63edf49dc293dd90373066b4d4?family=Whitney);

h1.a{
  font-family: "Whitney", Arial;
}

h1.b{
  font-family: "UniSansW01-Heavy", Arial;
}
```

Here is the javascript:

```js
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1 className="a">
          UPPER TEXT 
        </h1>
        <br />
        <br />
        <h1 className="b">
          LOWER TEXT
        </h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I run the development server with `npm start` the fonts apply perfectly. When I deploy the production build to Firebase, the fonts just default to fall back to Arial.
I checked the css files in the build folder and the imports are present. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Check network tab of the browser. I suspect the problem is with loading CSS from different host.

Comment: I checked the Chrome devtools source tabs for both and it appears that the issue is somewhat related to what @vvs said. In localhost:3000, the font servers appear as a source, compared to the firebase-hosted version where they do not. I am still not sure of the solution though.

Comment: Consider this https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/Cross-Origin.

Comment: I do think that CORS was the issue here. I just got it to work by downloading `otf` files and using @font-face. I am going to try uploading the font files to an S3 bucket to test CORS. I will post my results as an answer to this question if applicable.